# How to increase height of element using javascript ( document.getElementById('x').style.height+14 ) ?

Tags: javascript

I have this CSS:

```
#x { height: 100px; }
```

And this JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('x').onkeydown = function () {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        var h = Number(this.style.height);
        this.style.height = h + 14 + 'px';
    }
};
```

`document.getElementById('x').style.height+14`

What should I do?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Are you asking how to increase `document.getElementById('x').style.height` by `14`? Are you asking about some problem with your existing code?

Comment: document.getElementById('x') height is 114px and I want to be

Comment: pass your event to your function then...nevermind

Comment: You should post some more explanation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
var h = this.offsetHeight;
```

instead of

```
var h = Number(this.style.height);
```

Comment: Would probably be helpful to explain why: `this.style.height` is `100px` and `Number('100px')` is `NaN` and not `100`. So the `h + 14 + 'px'` becomes `'NaNpx'`

Comment: @t.niese: `this.style.height` is likely empty in his case. See: http://jsfiddle.net/5ZYCj/

Comment: `this.style.height` will work for inline CSS, i.e `<div style="height:100px">` and for styles applied with JS, it doesn't grab styles external CSS.

Comment: @t.niese is right ParkJaeChin uses `style="height:...;"`, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140191/how-to-increase-height-of-element-using-javascript-document-getelementbyidx/18140501#comment26567264_18140191) comment. Try it in console `>>> var test = '10px'; undefined >>> Number(test); NaN`

Comment: @zerkmsoh yes you are right, mixed it up with `getComputedStyle`, it's a little bit to early in the morning. Anyway it is still a common mistake to forget that `height` could contain the unit.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/Z9UYX/) link.
When you get `element.style.height` you get string like `10px` and you must convert it to number by `parseInt` function to adding to it.
And when you applying new height you must use construction like `newHeight + 'px'` cause `style='height: 10;'` is wrong, you must use `px` or `%` or something else.
Example code:

```
var div = document.getElementById('testDiv');
div.style.height = (parseInt(div.style.height) + 10) + 'px !important';
```

And it's all works when element have a `height` in style attribute.

Comment: You never should use `parseInt` without specifying the `radix`.

Comment: yeah, Mozilla [says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) that's I must always use radix, but they says too if string dont't starts with `0` or `0x` then it's using 10 radix by default - I'll always hope on it)

Comment: Sometimes it only works when you use getComputedStyle('element').getPropertyValue('height')